# Isolating a variable inside the numerator

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-differentiation

While doing implicit differentiation I am asked to take a 2nd derivative of $$x^2+3y^2 = 9$$

The first derivative: $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-x}{3y}$$

Now the second derivative with the quotient rule I stopped here: $$\frac{-3y+3x\frac{dy}{dx}}{9y^2}$$

From here I need to isolate the $3x\frac{dy}{dx}$ and then solve for $\frac{dy}{dx}$. How do I get the $3x\frac{dy}{dx}$ out of the numerator?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what you want to achieve, but what about just using the equality you got for the first derivative to conclude?

Comment: @GitGud I forgot how to solve the 2nd derivative thanks for reminding me to just plug in the first derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should write a full equation $$\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{-3y+3x\frac{dy}{dx}}{9y^2}.$$  You have a value for $\frac {dy}{dx}$, so substitute it in and you are done.

Comment: OHHHHH. I forgot about that. Thank you so much! Now it makes sense. I was so lost in trying to figure out how to solve this. Thanks Ross.